# DEM with bathymetric contour lines in GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, dem, contour, bathymetry

I am trying to create a DEM from a bathymetric contour lines. Contours are in vector format and the elevation value is negative. To create the surface I have converted the contours in raster (v.to rast) and then I have used r.surf.contour, but It doesn't work. I think that it would be because the negative values of the created raster. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 4):

What are your region settings? I tried this set of commands, and succeeded to create a DEM with negative values, with no problems:

```
# Set region to low resoution
GRASS 7.0.0 (ITM):~ > g.region -p res=5

# The contour vector
GRASS 7.0.0 (ITM):~ > v.db.select test_ctours
cat|elev
1|-100
2|-80
3|-60
4|-40
5|-20

# Create rasterized contours
GRASS 7.0.0 (ITM):~ > v.to.rast test_ctours type=line use=attr attribute=elev out=test_ctours --o
# Create DEM
GRASS 7.0.0 (ITM):~ > r.surf.contour test_ctours out=test_dem
GRASS 7.0.0 (ITM):~ > r.info test_dem
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Map:      test_dem                       Date: Fri May  8 13:02:06 2015    |
 | Mapset:   Arava                          Login of Creator: micha           |
 | Location: ITM                                                              |
 | DataBase: /home/micha/GIS/grass                                            |
 | Title:     ( test_dem )                                                    |
 | Timestamp: none                                                            |
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 |                                                                            |
 |   Type of Map:  raster               Number of Categories: 0               |
 |   Data Type:    DCELL                                                      |
 |   Rows:         200                                                        |
 |   Columns:      300                                                        |
 |   Total Cells:  60000                                                      |
 |        Projection: Transverse Mercator                                     |
 |            N:     500000    S:     499000   Res:     5                     |
 |            E:     211500    W:     210000   Res:     5                     |
 |   Range of data:    min = -100  max = -20                                  |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Data Description:                                                        |
 |    generated by r.surf.contour                                             |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Comments:                                                                |
 |    r.surf.contour input="test_ctours" output="test_dem"                    |
 |                                                                            |
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The point is that r.surf.contour is very slow when there are large gaps between the contour lines. So, either very dense contours, or a rougher resolution setting might help.

Comment: In addition, see also http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Contour_lines_to_DEM

Answer (score 1):

This are the settings of my vector layer:

```
g.region -p vector=CT_ISOBATAS_5m_ETRS89@froga                                  
projection: 1 (UTM)
zone:       30
datum:      etrs89
ellipsoid:  grs80
north:      4818925.16988824
south:      4791485.92527958
west:       486512.5000001
east:       601274.08203047
nsres:      1.00011826
ewres:      1.00010965
rows:       27436
cols:       114749
cells:      3148253564
```

After executing the v.to.rast command, I get a raster, and it seems that is correct (pixels have the value of the elevation)

```
r.info isobatas5rast                                                            
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
 | Map:      isobatas5rast                  Date: Fri May  8 14:45:44 2015    |
 | Mapset:   froga                          Login of Creator: gepalgoi        |
 | Location: froga1                                                           |
 | DataBase: /gscratch/gepalgoi                                               |
 | Title:    Categories ( isobatas5rast )                                     |
 | Timestamp: none                                                            |
 |----------------------------------------------------------------------------|
 |                                                                            |
 |   Type of Map:  raster               Number of Categories: 0               |
 |   Data Type:    DCELL                                                      |
 |   Rows:         27436                                                      |
 |   Columns:      114749                                                     |
 |   Total Cells:  3148253564                                                 |
 |        Projection: UTM (zone 30)                                           |
 |            N: 4818925.16988824    S: 4791485.92527958   Res: 1.00011826    |
 |            E: 601274.08203047    W: 486512.5000001   Res: 1.00010965       |
 |   Range of data:    min = -115  max = -5                                   |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Data Source:                                                             |
 |    Vector Map: CT_ISOBATAS_5m_ETRS89@froga                                 |
 |    Original scale from vector map: 1:1                                     |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Data Description:                                                        |
 |    generated by v.to.rast                                                  |
 |                                                                            |
 |   Comments:                                                                |
 |    v.to.rast input="CT_ISOBATAS_5m_ETRS89@froga" layer="1" type="line" \   |
 |    output="isobatas5rast" use="attr" attribute_column="CONTOUR" value=1\   |
 |     memory=300                                                             |
 |                                                                            |
 +----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Then, I interpolate the surface, but the resulting raster is exactly the same as the previos one. There is no an interpolate surface (although is hasn't give any error message):

```
r.surf.contour --overwrite input=isobatas5rast@froga output=mdt_isobata5
```

Comment: Note the non-square pixels - better to use the align flag -a of g.region with res=XX to set it properly (you need to do that at the very beginning of your workflow to not propagate odd resolution throughout your work).

Comment: I have used the flag -a as you said but it doesn't work. The resulting raster is again exactly the same as the one I have rasterised.

Comment: g.region -p -a raster=isobatas5rast@froga nsres=1 ewres=1                       
v.to.rast --overwrite input=CT_ISOBATAS_5m_ETRS89@froga type=line output=isobatas5rast use=attr attribute_column=CONTOUR

Comment: You  region settings are giving you rasters of over 3 billion cells. Are you sure you need such high resolution? If I'm not mistaken, each raster layer will take 25GB of disk space.

Comment: Yes, I need a DEM of very high resolution of a wide area. I am using a computer with large capacities for it.